# jquery clone() and append li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone the current contents of the li with the  nested in them also and append them to the ul.

Here is the html

```
<ul id="gList">
<li><a id="1" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a id="2" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a id="3" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
<li><a id="4" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

and my jquery which does not work.

```
$('ul#gList').clone('li>*').append('ul#gList');
```

I had done it last night but for some reason sublime has overwritten the file and it has stopped working.

Comment: Your html has id gList and your javascript is targeting ul#gridList this maybe your problem

Comment: is that all your html or do you have a `ul` with an id of `gridList`??

Comment: thats the only ul in the html.  $('ul') in console gives me <ul id="gList">

Comment: its not there.  Apologies I typed the question out instead of copying it.  All updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you are not firing the code when the `ul` is ready, try:

```
$(function () {
    var clones = $('#gList li').clone();
    // set to varaible to make op clear
    $('#gList').append(clones);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/motihacogu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: updated: added a doc ready and set the cloned el to a var, this works fine when I try it http://jsbin.com/motihacogu/edit?html,js,output